# primary key used in one to many relationship in postgresql for project

Tags: database, postgresql, project, primary-key, one-to-many

I am creating a final year project-online shopping system, but I am having doubt regarding the primary key to be used in tables as it has to get auto inserted in other tables to extract data.
Example if I am having two tables shop and products here relation between shop and product is one to many means one shop has many products. I tried to use serial as a primary key but it's not working well because it's accepting only number of product which are equal to number shops.

so what should I do to resolve this issue as at the time of inserting product through GUI we can just enter product name

Please can you help me out ???

I have attached some images regarding this database.[`Image giving error`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAbM3.png)

This is what I have done in Postgres

```
check_serial=# create table shop(id serial primary key,name text);
CREATE TABLE
check_serial=# create table product(pid serial primary key,pname text,id serial references shop(id) on delete cascade on update set null);
CREATE TABLE
check_serial=# insert into shop(name) values('abc');
INSERT 0 1
check_serial=# insert into shop(name) values('xyz');
INSERT 0 1
check_serial=# insert into product(pname) values('soap');
INSERT 0 1
check_serial=# insert into product(pname) values('tooth paste');
INSERT 0 1
check_serial=# insert into product(pname) values('shampoo');
ERROR:  insert or update on table "product" violates foreign key constraint "product_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(3) is not present in table "shop".
check_serial=# insert into product(pname) values('pqr');
ERROR:  insert or update on table "product" violates foreign key constraint "product_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(4) is not present in table "shop".
check_serial=#
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, you should create only many to one relation and remove relation one to many from shop. Then you can use this model without any problems. Just insert product name with shop id and also you can join product to shop by id.

Comment: I think you didn't understood my question. I have two tables shop and product so one shop has many products,therefore primary key of shop should pass as foreign key to products table now here I am getting confused what data type should I give to primary key if i give serial data to primary key of shop it is accepting only one product detail it means it's not working with serial as primary key and if I use int as primary key it will not update shop id passed as foreign key to product table..... Actually I am creating final year project online shopping system can you help me with it's database

Comment: Structure of your tables should be like: Shop with bigserial, unique and auto increment id. Product with bigserial, unique and auto increment id and also shop_id bigint foreign key references to shop.id. First of all you should create table shop and insert row into the shop table, next create table product and when you insert rows to the product table you should pass existing id of you shop from shop table to the product.shop_id. So, this is many to one relation. And you can get all rows from table product by shop_id.